# Creating an HTML or PDF "file" in memory and streaming it in Node.js

Tags: node.js, file

I have a need to create a pdf or html document within a Node.js express API which then sends that document over HTTP to an API managing our CMS.

So functionally I would like to create the document and POST it as part of a multipart-form upload POST request to an external service.

I see how to do this if after I create the file, I then turn around and write it disk.  After that point I can do a read stream of the file from that path to format the POST request with the file.

However I'm wondering how I can perform this action without writing the file to disk and then reading it into a read stream.  It seems I should be able to accomplish this without that IO.

Anybody able to point me to a good example or library that does something along these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend Writable and/or Readable streams. By the first look [this library](https://github.com/paulja/memory-streams-js) do what you need, with the same way - extending built-in streams.